# Using Spring batch to read a file and write to a Map

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, spring-batch

**Background**

I am fairly new to Spring batch and have the following requirement :

1. Read a file with a minumum of million records (CSV, pipe delimited etc)
2. Load each row in the file into a Map with key as the first column and value as a domain object/POJO.

I understand that Spring batch has something known as chunk oriented processing where one configures a reader, processor and a writer to process a certain number of records governed by the commit-interval. This can further be scaled using a task executor for the reader or by adding another layer of multithreading through partitioning.

**Question**

As explained in point 2 above, I want to load my file into a Map. For the sake of discussion, lets say I implement the following ItemWriter that aggregates the chunks into a Map.

```
public class MapItemWriter implements ItemWriter<SomePOJO> {

    private Map<String, SomePOJO> somePojoMap; 

    public MapItemWriter() {
        System.out.println("Writer created ");
        somePojoMap= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SomePOJO>();
    }

    public void write(List<? extends SomePOJO> item) throws Exception {
        if (item != null && item.size() > 0) {
            for (SomePOJO data : item) {
                String uniqueId = data.Id();
                somePojoMap.put(uniqueId, data);
             }
        }
    }

    public Map<String, SomePojo> getSomePojoMap() {
        return somePojoMap;
    }
}
```

Since I have access to my ItemWriter bean, I can later call getSomePojoMap to get the aggregated Map of records in my file; however, holding a Map like this in the ItemWriter doesn't feel like the best way to go about this. Another concern is that the use of a ConcurrentHashMap may degrade performance but I don't see any other way in which I can aggregate the file into a Map in a thread safe manner.

Is there a better way to aggregate my file into a Map rather than holding a Map in my writer and using a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: why do you want to load the data into the map? what happens with the map after it is filled?

Comment: @MichaelPralow We have a legacy system that loads data from files into a Map (one for each file). We want to replace the data loading layer with Spring batch. These maps are used in the aggregation layer which aggregates the data from different Maps into a master object which is sent on a JMS queue listened to by another system. We don't want to change the aggregation layer because it will mean revamping the whole legacy system. We want to improve the data loading performance. If we keep the interface to the aggregation layer the same it can can continue working as if nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more or less it. You could make small improvements like putting the map in a separate bean, which would allow you to have a different lifetime for the writer bean and the map and also decouple the readers of the map from the writer. For instance you could put the map in a job scoped bean and still have the writer a singleton, for instance.

You only need a `ConcurrentHashMap` if your job is partitioned into multiple threads (I'm assuming you don't want the map shared across jobs).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The `Map` is not shared across jobs. Also, the step that reads the file is going to use a Tasklet with a TaskExecutor or I may even split the file into physical partitions on disk. The end result of my job will be the Map containing the file contents. My job has only one step which reads the file and loads to a `Map`. Most examples I have come across on the internet use the writer for writing to a file or database. I feel like I am using an ItemWriter for something it was not designed for. Would this be frowned upon by a veteran Spring Batch user?

Comment: @CKing I don't know if I can speak for a veteran Spring Batch user; I can say though, that you're not using what Spring Batch chunked steps were designed for: the ability to transactionally process chunks of data one at a time, with optional retrying, skipping and restarting. You're not effectively processing the chunks one a time insofar as keeping the previous chunks around in memory, and your writer's actions cannot be rollback. But the first characteristic seems due to your legacy requirements and the second is not really a probably because your writer can never fail.

Comment: That's exactly my worry. Using a framework for something it was not designed for. My requirement does not fit the typical Spring batch use case. I am mainly choosing Spring batch for it's off-the-shelf flat file parsing API and scaling options that accompany it. If my data-set increases in the future (which usually does happen), I can scale my application with various options Spring batch provides. Do you know any other frameworks I should be looking at if file reading scalability is my only goal?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use File Item Writer.

I assume that this map should be written to a file. probably a flat file ( txt)

If this is the case try to use [FlatFileItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#FlatFileItemWriter) . In case you need to write this data to a xml file , you can use [StaxEventItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#StaxEventItemWriter).

Even if your don't need to write the data to a file ( need only the map in the end of the batch processing). I think that it will be "cheaper" to write the data to a file and afterwards reading the whole map from the file. Saving the map within the job scope means that this object will be persist in db in every chunk, and will be retrieved from db on every chunk, quite expensive operation.

Comment: Wouldn't I be going around in circles if I load the data into a `Map` from a file and then write it back to a file and then load it again in a Map when I need it?

Comment: In case that you do no logic with the extracted data, I don't think you will enjoy from the read-in-chunk benefit. Still spring batch have more features  (retry, listeners etc) but reading in chucks and saving the map as job scope object will be expensive and not worthy.

Comment: I gave it some thought and what you say is correct. Reading in chunks have no benefit if I am simply loading the data into a `Map`; however, that's not the case. I am going to be applying some filters on the data and eliminating those records that don't satisfy the filter criteria. Something like a database-where clause.